# Delete/Collapse Binary Tree in PHP

Tags: php, tree, binary-tree

I have a table like this

```
----------------------------------
CUSTOMER_ID    | REF_CUSTOMER_ID |   
----------------------------------
1              | NULL            | 
2              | 1               | 
3              | 2               | 
4              | 2               | 
5              | 3               |
6              | 3               | 
7              | 4               |
8              | 4               |  
9              | 1               |  
----------------------------------
```

from that table it is known that 2 is child of 1 and 3,4 is child of 2 etc..
 which makes the tree look like this

```
                1
                |
        ------------------
        |                |
        2                9
        |                |
    -----------     
    |        |                
    3        4   
    |        |
  -----    -----
  |   |    |   |
  5   6    7   8
```

okay , after each parent have 2 child and 4 leaf, in this case 2 have child of 3 and 4 and leaf of 5,6,7,8 the tree will have to collapse. Which mean it would only left 1 in the tree. But since 2 is a child of 1, and 3,4 is a leaf of 1 and 1 haven't complete its cycle yet so 1 cant collapse yet.

Question

**How do I still collapse the tree of 2 as root but maintain the tree of one with its child and leaf? How do I approach this? Do I have to create another table ? Or just use existing table?**

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'collapse'? I don't understand your question... Perhaps you can post a graph of what you want the tree to look like in the end.

Comment: Also, 3 and 4 aren't leaves. A leaf node is one that has no children, but in this example, 3 and 4 both have two children each.

Comment: Collapse -- meaning i want to delete the tree with all its nodes.But in this case IF 2 is a root the whole tree with 2 as ROOT have to collapse. But 1 as a root havent complete a cycle yet, so 1 can't collapse. I know in the figure above 3 and 4 is not leaf. But if 1 is root and you ignore the 5678, 3 and 4 is a leaf for 1. The cycle is complete only up to 2 level of a tree. So meaning you have to look separately between 2 and 1. But in a BIG TREE structure, both are related to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use additional table, you can delete the tree using recursion:

Pseudocode:

```
function deleteChildBranches(node)
{
    get left and right child nodes
    if(there's left branch node)
       deleteANode(left branch node)
    if(there's right branch node)
       deleteANode(right branch node)       
}

function deleteANode(node)
{
    get left and right child nodes
    if(there's left branch node)
       deleteANode(left branch node)
    if(there's right branch node)
       deleteANode(right branch node)
    delete this node
}
```

This code will first traverse a tree to the bottom, nodes are deleted from the bottom to the top.

Comment: If i did this, the tree of 2 as ROOT will be deleted from the database. Correct. But after deletion of 2 as ROOT, I want 2 to maintain as CHILD of 1 which in the figure above is not suppose to collapse because the right child of 1 which is 9 doesnt have a child. I want to delete from the whole tree if 2 as root. But Maintain 2 as child of 1.

Comment: i'm not sure what you want to achieve. But i've added a function that doesn't delete the node where the deletion starts.